# Android build does not pass

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a smartphone application with react-native.
It worked fine until last week, but it stopped working from December 7th.
When I raised the version of Gradle, I got the following error.

===========================================================

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
92 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 90 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/project/node_modules/react-native-config/android/dotenv.gradle' line: 85
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData.getVariantConfiguration() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/project/node_modules/react-native-config/android/dotenv.gradle' line: 85
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData.getVariantConfiguration() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:9)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! XXXXX android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the XXXXX android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

===========================================================

·clean
·Delete .gradle under android and rebuild
・ Delete cache
I tried, but the same error keeps appearing.

Two days have passed since I couldn't find a solution like this even after searching.
If anyone knows a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have updated your npm and expo, and in your packson.json, the version should be like (equal or higher)

```
 "expo": "^39.0.0",

 "react": "16.13.1",
```

then rebuild

(please also make sure that all Module compile SDK version and support library version should be same as project compile SDK version and support library version.)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
After reviewing the library and SDK versions, the error changed as follows.
I tried adding the jetify package, but the error did not change ...
If you know the solution here, please let me know.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  /project/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:25: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.

Comment: * Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)

Comment: Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
/project/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:25: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.

Comment: The above 3 comments are excerpts of some of the error details.

Comment: Since you have cleaned your cache , updated your SDK versions but it still fails. If I were you I will use a new PC to reinstall the nodejs and expo, and then put all the source codes back into this new PC and then install all additional modules and rebuild. (if you do not have a new PC, you can backup all the data of the project , uninstall the nodejs and expo and then reinstall)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll give it a try.